# Need to count runs of consecutive indices

Tags: python, pandas

I need to count instances where there's at least 4 consecutive values that meet a criteria in pandas. The code below gives me an Int64Index:

```
    IN: vals = chunk[chunk[col] > ninetieth].index
    OUT: Int64Index([427, 429, 430, 431, 436, 470, 471, 472, 473, 478, 518, 519, 520,
        521, 522, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569],
       dtype='int64')
```

I can get what I want this way:

```
count = 0
i = 0
while i < range(len(vals)):
    try:
        if vals[i] + 3 == vals[i + 3]:
            count += 1
            i += 3
        else: i += 1
    except: break
```

But there HAS to be an easier, less terrible way, right?

ETA: After further clarification, the count should increment for each run of at least 4 consecutive values, and not again until there's a gap.

Comment: My question, if it isn't clear, is how can I accomplish this in pandas without all of the extra steps. There must be some sort of built in function I'm missing.

Comment: Did you  mean `while i < len(vals):` instead?  That code doesn't look like it'll work.

Comment: That *would* be prettier, but this works despite that error.

Comment: vals is a list of indexes where the condition holds, and consecutive indexes will differ by 1. However, the question said "at least 4", but you are counting exactly four. If it were met by five consecutive rows, you would count that as two instances.

Comment: @mauve: you're comparing an int (i) to a list or a range object, which will always give True in Python 2 (which you shouldn't be using, but I guess you must be), and fail with a TypeError in Python 3.

Comment: @KennyOstrom thank you for catching my error! I do need to count 1 for each consecutive run and then move to the next nonconsecutive and check if that meets the consecutive condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to take the difference with a range, basically subtracting off the consecutive part, and then do a groupby:

```
v2 = vals - np.arange(len(vals))
result = (v2.to_series().groupby(v2).size() >= 4).sum()
```

which gives me

```
In [141]: result
Out[141]: 3
```

This works because

```
In [142]: v2 = vals - np.arange(len(vals))

In [143]: v2
Out[143]: 
Int64Index([427, 428, 428, 428, 432, 465, 465, 465, 465, 469, 508, 508, 508,
            508, 508, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550],
           dtype='int64')
```

where each consecutive run now has the same number (not the same number as we started with, but that doesn't matter here).  Then:

```
In [144]: v2.to_series().groupby(v2).size()
Out[144]: 
427    1
428    3
432    1
465    4
469    1
508    5
550    5
dtype: int64

In [145]: (v2.to_series().groupby(v2).size() >= 4).sum()
Out[145]: 3
```